# What is a complete intersection?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intuition

I was reading and I encountered something that goes: We have degree $d$ polynomials in $s$ variables $F_1, ..., F_n$
with coefficients in integers. Let 
$X$ be the complete intersection defined by the simultaneous equations
$$
F_1(\mathbf{x}) = ... = F_n(\mathbf{x}). 
$$

I have looked up complete intersection on Wikipedia, but I still quite 
don't understand exactly what it is. Could someone possibly
give me an explanation of what complete intersection is and why the definition
is that way? Thanks!

Comment: Complete intersection just means the codimension of your variety is  exactly the number of equations you used to define that variety.

Comment: @LiYutong:  Not exactly --- it means that the codimension is exactly equal to the minimal number of equations *necessary* to define the variety, not necessarily to the number of equations you happened to use.